# Update panel with each row in repeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have repeater and when i put update panel in each row its still loading all other update panels is there any reason for this?

It should only update that part only that is i want to achieve.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="grd" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class=" table-serviceline table table-hover table-bordered">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="service-line-item" id="<%#"serviceline"+ Eval("ClaimServiceID") %>">

                <td class="fw65">

                    <table class="table-small-pad">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblID" ClientIDMode="Static"  Text='<%#Container.ItemIndex+1 %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>                                                   
                        </tr>                                               
                    </table>

                </td>

                <td class="fw150">
                    <table class="table-small-pad">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
                                  <ContentTemplate>
                                  <div class="input-group">                                
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCODE" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("Code") %>' ToolTip="Code" MaxLength="15" />
                                     <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                                  </div>
                                  </ContentTemplate>
                                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </td>                                                   
                        </tr>                                              
                    </table>
                </td>                                       
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Why don't use only one updatepanel outside Repeater? Where is databinding code?

Comment: Did my answer help?  Please help the community out and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the combo of

```
UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

and

```
ChildrenAsTriggers="True"
```

in the UpdatePanel is what you are looking for.  If you don't set the first parameter, UpdatePanels update on any postback.

Comment: Additionally, need to find a way of assigning different ID per UpdatePanel.